# CSS: how to set content by class?

Tags: html, css

In one table, I have fixed content for each class.

```
    <td class="matched">Matched</td>
    ...
    <td class="not-matched">Not Matched</td>
```

Is there way to avoid typing content every time?

```
    <td class="matched"></td>
    ...
    <td class="not-matched"></td>
```

Comment: are you using some kind of template engine or pure HTML / CSS?

Comment: `:after` or `:before` come to mind.

Comment: @Martin, I prefer just HTML/CSS.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, looks like it is, thank you!

Comment: In my opinion its preferable to use `javascript` for this type of feature. In this case the text will be directly injected in the balise and not as a `::after` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `::before` or `::after` selectors to create a pseudo-element, and apply a content to it.

```css
.matched::before {
  content: "Matched";
}

.not-matched::before {
  content: "Not Matched";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="matched"></td>
    <td class="not-matched"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="matched"></td>
    <td class="not-matched"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="matched"></td>
    <td class="not-matched"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The downside of this is that those texts are not selectable.

---

You can also optimize the code like below:

```css
[class]::before {
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="matched"></td>
    <td class="not-matched"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="matched"></td>
    <td class="not-matched"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="matched"></td>
    <td class="not-matched"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```